# Redirect all non-www to www except one subdirectory using htaccess.

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

If want to redirect all non-www requests to my site to the www version. All I need to do is add the following code to my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that when I write for example mydomain.com/products-1 (hidden URL for mydomain.com/products?category=1), all parameters become visible, even though they are specified on the .htaccess file, and I get an output url (after the redirect) of www.mydomain.com/products-1?category=1

How can I fix this? Is there any kind of problems with the .htaccess code above?

Comment: In your title, you say one subdomain but in your code you have a directory listed?  Is this a subdomain issue (sub.example.com) or a directory issue. example.com/sub?

Comment: It is a subdirectory issue (example.com/sub). Sorry if I wasn't clear enought.

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess OR your have more rules in there?

Comment: It has a lot more rules in it. It has over 60 lines.

Comment: Yes I suspected that. Move this rule to top of your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @anubhava, followed your recommendation, now works perfect! :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your `RewriteRule`:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

I prefer this because it will catch all *.domain.com.  If that is not what you want, then use your original HTTP_HOST rule.

If my logic is working this morning, this rule should rewrite any requests that do not match:

www.example.com
and do not contain

/subfolder

to 
www.domain.com/URI

Comment: But it will also solve the "visible parameters" problems I had on the URL also?

Comment: The rule above should not have any bearing on visible parameters.  Sounds like you have other rewrite rules that may not be correct.

Comment: I know, but the problem I am having is that after the www is added to the URLs (using the code I listed above), the URL parameters which are currently hidden become visible.

Comment: Try removing the `L` from the rewrite rule.  This could be truncating your rewrite process.  See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: I don't know anything about regex or htaccess. I wouldn't know if that would fix my problem by reading the guide.

Comment: The problem is not with the rule I provided. It does what you asked. The issue is how you are handling the other rewrite rules.  Make sure this rule is above other rules that handle the URLs.   Try with and without the `L`.  Without the full ruleset it will be difficult to diagnose your error.